# How to migrate from SOAP (JIRA 6) to REST Api (JIRA 7)

Tags: rest, soap, jira, jira-rest-api, suds

I need to migrate to JIRA REST Api because we have a version upgrade to JIRA 7  and I cannot use JIRA SOAP api: mainly the server to which I connect is wrong:

```
    SOAP_SERVER     = http://myServer/jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl
    Client(self.JIRA_SOAP_SUDS_SERVER)
    auth=client.service.login("user", "pass")
```

The URL above simply gives ERROR 404 (Means page cannot be found) (I'm using python)

Does Anyone knows please what new URL should I use now or if I can keep using SOAP in JIRA 7

Thanks a lot

Comment: you can use this format "http://host:port/context/rest/api-name/api-version/resource-name" one example being "/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-1", also do not use SOAP in JIRA 7 as it was sunset of SOAP in JIRA 6

Comment: @prasshant Thanks but didn't work. My project is situated at site/jira/projects/projectName/issues/. I tried smth like http://Myserver.com/rest/api/2/projects/project-name but didn't work. If you have any other suggestions it is welcome.